# Absolute convergence of double sum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

When computing a double sum, if $\sum_{n,m \in N \times N} |f(m,n)|$ converges, then we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} f(m,n) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(m,n)$.

For checking convergence of $\sum_{n,m \in N \times N} |f(m,n)|$, can I sum the $\{|f(m,n)|\}_{m,n}$ matrix however I like? For example, by adding row by row or column by column? What if I did something weird, like summing across the middle diagonal $|f(n,n)|$, then sum along diagonal $|f(n+1,n)|$, then sum along diagonal $|f(n, n+1)|$ etc...

Comment: Yes. This is a special case of Fubini-Tonelli Theorem, where both measures are the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: as the sum involves only positive terms doing any order will make no difference